# ReactJS form control, display vs if else

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a big form with many branches. I am wondering if there is any performance difference between

```
 <Box display={type == type.RatioBased ? "none" : "flex"}>
```

and

```
{type == type.RatioBased ? "" : (<Box >......</Box>)}
```

Any suggestions helps

Comment: `type == type.RatioBased` - am I missing something or can this never be true? If `type` is an object, it can't equal one of it's properties

Comment: yes, there is a typo, it should be type === TYPE.RatioBased, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

If you used the first choice you will populate the `DOM` with an unwanted component and that will lead to a bigger `DOM` and can slow the processing of the `DOM`.

In the second choice, the component `Box` will get removed from the `DOM`. It’s better to go with the second choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so to be clear, the DOM is still rendered event when display is none, just not been shown